# SQLITE database with iOS and ICloud

Tags: ios, sqlite, icloud

I found lot off tutorials related to iCloud and ios synchronization.

```
But There is no any tutorial for 
"How to save sqlite databse on iCloud and how to edit database on iCloud"
```

- So is there any way to save and edit SQLITE database on iCloud through iOS application??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware there is no way to edit anything on iCloud it is only a means of storing information between devices you own.

If you want to edit the database you will need to do it on the device, then setup you app to sync with iCloud after your edits are done.

Comment: CStreel thanks for the answer. In applications which are not used Icloud we save Sqlite database on Doc directory and during the life cycle of Application we open database from Doc Directory edit it and then again we save it in Doc directory. So i have a confusion for iCloud 1. First we should first get Database from iCloud and save it on Doc directory and during the life cycle of Application we open database from Doc directory and we done with database we again save it on database.   So these are the perfect steps or there is another way to deal with sqlite database and ICloud??

Comment: before any alteration is made you should sync with iCloud to ensure you have the latest version of the file

Comment: Ok i understand the flow and thank you very much  for help. Is there any tutorial or example related to this topic?

Answer (score 1):

You should not store sqlite database in iCloud. iCloud is not meant for storing database files.

Comment: we can store sqlite database in icloud

Comment: Yes we can store database in iCloud. You just need to specify how much your requirement to do so.